# WebApi action filter dependency injection not called when applied globally

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a simple WebApi action (exception) filter...

```
public class LogExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    [Dependency]
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        Logger.Fatal(context.Exception, "Critical exception in request to WebApi controller.");

        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Internal Server Error."),
            ReasonPhrase = "Critical Exception"
        });

    }
}
```

A Unity filter provider...

```
public class UnityFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly ActionDescriptorFilterProvider _defaultProvider = new ActionDescriptorFilterProvider();

    public UnityFilterProvider(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var attributes = _defaultProvider.GetFilters(configuration, actionDescriptor);

        foreach (var attr in attributes)
        {
            _container.BuildUp(attr.Instance.GetType(), attr.Instance);
        }
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

And the following configuration for unity...

```
var providers = config.Services.GetFilterProviders().ToList();
config.Services.Add(typeof(IFilterProvider), new UnityFilterProvider(container));
var defaultprovider = providers.Single(i => i is ActionDescriptorFilterProvider);
config.Services.Remove(typeof(IFilterProvider), defaultprovider);

var logger = LogFactory.CreateWebApiLogger();
container.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(logger);
```

When the `[LogException]` attribute is applied to the controller, the dependency injection works correctly and the ILogger instance is available within the exception filter.

However, when I attempt to configure the filter globally...

```
config.Filters.Add(new LogExceptionAttribute());
```

the dependency is not resolved and I get a null reference exception whilst attempting to access the ILogger instance from within the filter.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    config.Filters.Add((IExceptionFilter)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(LogExceptionAttribute)));
```

APPEND

After your comment, I checked mine further.

I have Constructor dependency

```
public class LogExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    private ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public LogExceptionAttribute  (ILogger logger)
    {
        this.Logger  = logger;
    }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception != null)
        {
            this.Logger.LogException(context.Exception);
        }
    }
}
```

So my suggestion is to switch to constructor injection.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.Http.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to use constructor injection with actionfilterattribute?

Comment: The code I posted for "LogExceptionAttribute" (except for the name of the class) is exactly what I have........and probably why I have that slightly different syntax for my original code snipplet.

Comment: @JamesLaw - It is possible to use constructor injection, but you must separate the `IActionFilter` from the `Attribute` and register the `IActionFilter` globally as demonstrated in [passive attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/).